# Renderscript compiled files are not updated without cleaning the cache

Tags: renderscript

I am trying to run an app that uses Renderscript from NDK with just one file `main.rs`. I run it on Samsung Galaxy S7 Android 7.0.

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 25
renderscriptTargetApi 23
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
renderscriptNdkModeEnabled true
```

First run it works perfectly, but it does not update the compiled Renderscript on second and consequent launches. So I modify the body of my RS function, but on reinstall it stays the same on the phone.

I have three files in the cache directory:

```
main.bc
main.o
librs.main.so
```

For the first and consequent runs those files have the same `last modified` timestamp. So it seems that they are not recompiled on update. Only removal of the files helps to update the functionality when the code changes.

What is wrong? Why are those files not updated on the code change?

If you need more information, please leave a comment, I'll update the question.

Comment: Which model of S7 do you have?

Comment: @sakridge SM 930F

Answer (score 0):

RenderScript caches the compilation during the first run. It will / should recompile the .bc file if there is a change to the .bc file.

Try "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1", and modify your code to see if the auto-recompilation happens or not.

If the CPU driver works fine, it means that Samsung driver has a bug invalidating the code cache.

Comment: no, "adb shell setprop debug.rs.default-CPU-driver 1" does not help :( Code modification in .fs file still do not change behavior of the program unless you manually delete the cache.

Comment: hmm, is this only happening on S7, does emulator work? Do you have InstantRun enabled?

Comment: On emulator it works fine it only doesn't work on Samsung with NDK. When you use Renderscript from Java it works fine even on device.

Comment: I don't use Instant Run.